# how to pass a null parameter to date field in mysql procedure using python

Tags: python, mysql, stored-procedures

I'm new to the Mysql,so i'm getting the problem while passing the null value to date field from the python script calling the procedure.Can you please help me out

I have table in mysql db_test with fields name and date,date column allows null value.

i call the procedure from python like these

```
cursor.execute("CALL date_insert(%s,%s) ;" %('john',None))
```

But it shows an error

```
Error No:1292 Incorrect value 'None' for the date column
```

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
cursor.execute("CALL date_insert(%s,%s) ;" % ('john', 'NULL')
```

Or

```
cursor.execute("CALL date_insert(%s,%s) ;" % ('john', '\\N')
```

You might even need:

```
cursor.execute('CALL date_insert("%s", %s) ;' % ('john', 'NULL')
```

Just remember that while they are used similarly the various languages:

None, NULL, Null, null, NIL, 0, void, void *, '', "". <>, ?

are not the same and not necessarily interchangeable.

Comment: I try with Null instead of None as your suggestion but still i getting the error as (1292, "Incorrect date value: 'Null' for column 'amc_date' at row 1")

Comment: @Srilatha NULL is not the same as Null - Many languages are case dependent especially for "special" or "reserved" names.

Answer (score 0):

Try `NULL` instead of `None` for MYSQL:

```
cursor.execute("CALL date_insert(%s,%s) ;" %('john','NULL'))
```

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
cursor.execute("CALL date_insert(%s,%s) ;" % ('john', 'NULL')
```

`None` is the Python's way to represent empty objects. MySQL do not have any idea what it is. Instead,MySQL uses `'NULL'` for representing empty values.

Refer "[MySQL - Working with Null](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/working-with-null.html)" for more details.